# Why does using SwiftUI code give me a memory error?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Can you please help me solve this error that I am getting and how to get rid of it? It is happening in my SwiftUI code.
This is the error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16ed17ff0)

I tried to clean the error but did not work.
This is my code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct PostinksApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            JournalEntriesListView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No way we can help with this with so little information. Do you have any idea what part of your code it is that might be the cause of this?

Comment: A related article, https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/exc-bad-access-crash/